# IcedTea web applet plugin for Firefox

Tags: icedtea-web

Running Firefox 51 on my mac and would like to use icedtea web applet plugin. The instructions provided in https://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web#Plugin is not clear for mac. 
Is there anyway to use icedteaweb applet plugin for firefox running on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The support of plugins to run Applets has been removed from most browser.
It is no longer recommended to embed Applets into webpages.

See also: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/11809182?hl=en